# phpgmailer stopped working suddenly

Tags: php, phpmailer

I used `phpgmailer` to send emails and it was working smoothly. Today I tested my project and it's not working now.

```
   <?php                  
    require_once('class.phpgmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPGMailer();
    $mail->Username = 'username@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = '********';
    $mail->From = 'username@gmail.com';
    $mail->FromName = "<blah>";
    $mail->Subject = 'something';
    $mail->AddAddress('xyz@gmail.com');


    $mail->Body =  "Hello Sir"."\n"."     
    Your Password is : ."."";
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Send();

    if(!$mail->Send())
            {

       echo 'Message could not be sent.' ;
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

       exit;
            }
       echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Comment: What is the error you get when you echo `$mail->ErrorInfo`?

Comment: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: The following From address failed:username@gmail.com

Comment: i have been googling out this stuff for so many hours but no help :(
very upset with this.

Comment: with port=465 it gives a time out error
with port=25 it gives the mailer error !

Comment: Why is $mail->Send() used twice? I guess you'd need only the send() inside if check is needed. And make sure your password is correct. You  said you've used it a year back!

Comment: sorry by mistake ! avoid that sir

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you download [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/downloads/list) and try this code:

```
    require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host     = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port     = 465;
    $mail->Username = "from@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "****";
    $mail->FromName = "Sender name";
    $mail->Subject  = "test";
    $mail->Body     = "Test body";
    $mail->AddAddress('sender@mail.com');
    if(!$mail->Send()){
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }else{
        echo "Message has been sent";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@goose is right, remove the first `$mail->Send()` and leave the one in the if statement. If the `From` address is the same as the username email, then you don't need that either as it will take it from your gmail account.

Try that and see if it works.

EDIT: try adding the following;

```
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';  
    $mail->Password = 'password';
```

Try that and if there are errors, then it should give you more detail.

EDIT2: If that doesn't work then I suggest trying PHPMailer instead of PHPGmailer - and follow the tutorial here: http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/

Comment: What does the error say now? Are you sure that the Gmail password hasn't changed?

Comment: the same error !  and yes i have accessed that account right now with the same password :(

Comment: Call to undefined method PHPGMailer::SetFrom() in C:\xampp\htdocs\email_via_gmail\index.php on line 15

Comment: Ok...take away `$mail->SetFrom('email@gmail.com', 'From name');` and try that.

Comment: I've edited the answer once more, sorry that's all I can suggest.

Comment: hey with your example its giving this error

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
any idea??

Comment: Ahhh nightmare...ok try removing `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` and change the port to 25. If that doesn't work, try testing from another server because it could be a port block or something else.

Comment: Did you try it from another server?

Comment: ssl support was disabled in apache !
its working now !
thanks for help guys !

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure:

- `$mail->Username` is equal to `$mail->From`, and is correct
- `$mail->Password` is correct
- `$mail->FromName` does not contain "<" and ">" characters; just try `$mail->FromName = 'Test';`

Comment: now its giving this error ! SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.